# Meaning of NULL when using condition in gdal_calc

Tags: gdal, nodata, null, gdal-calc

I am confused with the results of using a condition in gdal_calc.
Initially I thought that gdal_calc was setting pixels to **nodata** where a condition is not met. 
In the documentation (http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html) it is said that the following command sets values of zero and below to **null**.

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A>0)" --NoDataValue=0
```

If I try this command:

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A>0)" --NoDataValue=-9999
```

The pixels where the condition is not met are set to **zero**.

Should I understand that the term **null** used in the documentation actually refers to pixels with a value of zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should understand the example so that

```
--calc="A*(A>0)"
```

makes all pixels with value zero or below into zero, and after that

```
--NoDataValue=0
```

sets the metadata to tell that zero means nodata. With you modified command the zeroes are set as before but you are telling that pixels with value -9999 are nodata, thus zeroes are not nodata. I am not sure but I suppose that if input data had originally nodata set to something else than -9999 then both the metadata and those nodata pixels would be converted into -9999.